# Analyze Code Coverage Disappear

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

i Run all created Unit Tests but i haven't option Analyze Code Coverage in Test and cant choose it from Test Explorer Window. Any Ideas? I have VS 2013 Professional

Answer (score 6):

According to http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx code coverage statistics in your testing tools are only available in Visual Studio 2013 Premium and Ultimate.

Answer (score 6):

**Requirements:**

**Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628(v=vs.120).aspx

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017,You can get the privilege from

**Visual Studio Enterprise**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628(v=vs.140).aspx